# Executed as user: xxxx\xxxxx. The config profile (xxxxxxx) could not be found. Process Exit Code 255. The step failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to execute a AWS CLI command from SQL Server Agent Job to sync backups to S3 bucket. I created a profile xxxxxxx and I am able to execute the following command successfully from cmd.exe
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" s3 --profile xxxxxx sync "C:\AutomatedBackups\Sequential\xxxxxxxxx\msdb" "s3://xxxxxxx/AutomatedBackups/Sequential/xxxxxxxxxx/msdb"

I am getting the following error when I try to execute from SQL Server Agent Job:
Executed as user: xxxx\xxxxx. The config profile (xxxxxxx) could not be found.  Process Exit Code 255.  The step failed.

Please advise.